# Loading Multiple TinyMCE instances is freezing the browser, solution?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mootools, tinymce

I have a page with multiple tinymce instances running at the same time and it's freezing the browser whenever it loads. It's taking not less than 15 seconds of waiting before I could use the browser again. I've tested this on IE9, FF6, and Chrome and all of them are freezing for some time while it is loading.

How could I prevent this freezing from happening? I have at least 10 textarea with tinymce attached to it in one page. Computer is running on core2duo with 4GB of RAM without any other program running, but this shouldn't matter as its supposed to work even with a lower spec PC.

Edit add JS code to load TinyMCE.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myTextbox = "10 name of textarea here";

tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "exact",
    elements: myTextbox,
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "paste,ibrowser",
    paste_remove_styles: true,
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
    plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,",
    theme_advanced_buttons5 : "pastetext,pasteword,selectall,iuploader,upload_status",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    setup : function(ed) {
    //IMAGE UPLOADER BUTTON 
    ed.addButton('iuploader', {
        title : 'Upload Image',
        image : '/www/images/admin/post_button_image_upload.gif',
        onclick : function() {
            load_image_uploader(this.id);
         }
      }),
    ed.addButton('upload_status', {
        title : 'Upload Status',
        image : '',
        onclick : function() {

         }
      });
    },

    // Content CSS
    content_css : "/www/js/tiny_mce/css/content.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

    // Style formats
    style_formats : [
        {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
        {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
        {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
        {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
        {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
        {title : 'Table styles'},
        {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
    ],

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }

});
```

Comment: ***How*** are you assigning the Tinymce editor instances onto the textarea elements? Please post your code.

Comment: Added the JS code that loads tinymce to the page in question.

Comment: I suspect that simply have 10+ textareas all being converted to TinyMCE is going to be a problem as in each case, a new instance of TinyMCE needs to be created. Have you considered only opening TinyMCE for the textarea the end-user wants to work with (say with an "edit" button or onclick event) instead of having all of them open on page load?

Comment: make sure all your html elements ('myTextbox') have different ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brett Henderson is right, loading 10 instances takes time. But, you'll never edit 10 at once, so opening TinyMCE only for the areas the user wants to work with will get you there.

Code to create TinyMCE instance for all textareas on click:

```
$$('textarea').each(function(e) {
    e.addEvent( 'click', function() {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, e.getProperty('id')) ;
    });
});
```

and change the mode to none:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "none",

    /* 
       other options etc 
    */

});
```

Comment: We did something similar, but this is better. If we'll do an update I'll change it to this method. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how this could be done with Tiny-React?
They are initialized when the page loads, or every time the component is re-rendered, but I can't get them to initialize when they are clicked.

Comment: `mode` has been deprecated from Tiny v6.0 and above

Answer (score 1):

```
tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "exact",
            elements : "ajaxfilemanager, ajaxfilemanager_1",
            theme : "advanced", ....



<textarea id="ajaxfilemanager" name="ajaxfilemanager" style="width: 100%; height: 500px" ></textarea>
<textarea id="ajaxfilemanager1" name="ajaxfilemanager_1" style="width: 100%; height: 500px" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

i use a click event to load tinyMCE on the clicked textarea, this helped me to use multiple tinyMCE editors on the same page without freezing the browser, it might not be the right way but it works for me. code:

```
            $('textarea').click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("tinyopen");
                //tinyMCE -------------
                    tinyMCE.init({

                        mode : "specific_textareas",
                        editor_selector : "tinyopen",

                        //  -----  Here comes your plugins and themes --------- //
                        //                                                      //  
                        //                                                      //  
                        //                                                      //
                        //  --------------------------------------------------- //

                        content_css : "path to css"

                    });
                //tinyMCE -------------
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that TinyMCE loads as many iframes as your instances. A better option in your case could be to use the inline version https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/inline/